# How do I validate the property of the model/class from the string in .Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have this web api controller that extending the Linq Dynamic to do ApplySort via a string

I could pass several sortby i.e: sort=id,name,datecreated into this web api. The challenge though I need to validate these strings (Id, Name, DateCreated etc etc) exist in the model/class's property before doing the Linq stuff. 
How do I do that?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Activities/{sort=id}/{pagenumber=1}/{pagesize=10}")]
[CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 60, ServerTimeSpan = 60)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetActivities(string sort, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var activities = await (db.Activities.Where(q => q.UserId == userId)
                              .AsQueryable().ApplySort(sort)
                              .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                              .Take(pageSize)).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(activities);
}
```

Comment: Can sort by several Properties? Then you have to split the sort-string and compare the parts.

Comment: Yes correct I need to do the split and check one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GetProperties():

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Activities/{sort=id}/{pagenumber=1}/{pagesize=10}")]
[CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 60, ServerTimeSpan = 60)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetActivities(string sort, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var propertyNames = typeof (Activity).GetProperties().Select(p=>p.Name).ToList();
    var sorts = sort.Split(',').Select(s=> s.Trim());
    foreach(var sortPart in sorts)
    {
       if(propertyNames.IndexOf(sortPart)<0)
       {
          throw//what ever should be done in error-case
       }
    }
    var activities = await (db.Activities.Where(q => q.UserId == userId)
                              .AsQueryable().ApplySort(sort)
                              .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                              .Take(pageSize)).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(activities);
}
```

Comment: I get an error in relation to propertyNames.IndexOf(sort)<0. There is no IndexOf under propertyNames

Comment: Never mind. Worked it out just need to append ToList()

Comment: @dcpartners Ok, I‘ll adapt my answer.